# Windows authentication in a Java/Tomcat server with an Android app

Tags: java, android, windows

My project is an Android application that communicates with a server. The server is written in Java, deployed in Tomcat, and running on a Windows Server host.

I need to provide authentication against Windows domain accounts. Basically I need to ask the user of the app to type in their username and password; send this data to the Tomcat server; and have the server authenticate it.

I'm having trouble finding a straight answer as to how to do this. Since my app is not a web site, I don't have the option to do browser redirects or anything like that, and obviously the Android device on which the app runs is not a Windows machine and will most likely not even be on the local network.

I don't really need to execute anything as the Windows user, I just need to know that they are who they say they are. Hopefully there is a simple way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use Java EE container-based form authentication, on the server you'll have to:

- [secure your web application](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/security-webtier.htm#BNCAS)
- [configure Tomcat to use Windows authentication](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-auth-howto.html)

On the client, you can:

- [POST](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html) application/x-www-form-urlencoded login data with the special keys in [the web form](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/security-webtier004.htm#BNCCA) (`j_password`, etc.)
- retain the session cookies in the response for subsequent interactions with the server

*I haven't tested the specifics with these exact technologies but approach is sound.*